# PHP file_put_contents() save file from ftp directory to local directory

Tags: php, file, ftp

I'm working with a site located at ftp. And I'm using `file_put_contents` function to create a log file. How should I write the `path` to **create** file on **my local machine**, say on D dir. THanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
int ftp_nb_get ( resource $ftp_stream , string $local_file , string $remote_file , int $mode [, int $resumepos = 0 ] )
```

More info here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nb-get.php

You can get a file from the remote server and save it to your local system.

Comment: I guess you misunderstood me. I should create this file by my own, b/c I don't have a permission to create a file at that ftp

Comment: Do you have the credentials to login on the ftp server?

Comment: I have. But I can't create files there. So I wished to know whether the file creates at all. Maybe I should find the way to know what permission I have

Answer (score 0):

The way to save it on my local machine was to use the ip address of my PC